# Set unique bean name javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException

Tags: java, spring, spring-amqp, spring-jmx

When I deploy 2 packages with Spring AMQP I get JMX error in the below code:

```
    @Bean
    public CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(HOST);
        connectionFactory.setBeanName("Test_123");
        return connectionFactory;
    }
```

I error `Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection:name=connectionFactory,type=CachingConnectionFactory`

Full error stack:
https://pastebin.com/CdU3epMz

How I can set unique name for connectionFactory?

EDIT:

I also tried to place application.properties under src/main/java/resources this configuration:

```
spring.jmx.enabled=false
spring.datasource.jmx-enabled=false
spring.jmx.default-domain=ssds # JMX domain name.
spring.jmx.server=apiServer # MBeanServer bean name.
management.metrics.export.jmx.domain=metccriddcs # Metrics JMX domain name.
management.metrics.export.jmx.enabled=false # Whether exporting of metrics to JMX is enabled.
management.endpoints.jmx.exposure.exclude=*
```

But I get the same error.

Comment: I think a simliar question is already handled here: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7075007/same-jmx-mbean-class-for-many-application-at-same-server)

Comment: Yes this solves my issue. Is there a way to use @Bean configuration to get the same result?

Comment: There are 2 ways i could think of. The first would be to disable jmx completely (if you don't need it). The second is setting the property `spring.application.name` for both and hoping that your exposed jmx-bean uses the application name as a prefix.

Comment: I already tries some configuration. See the updated post.

Answer (score 1):

The solution:

```
... implements ObjectNamingStrategy {

    @Override
    public ObjectName getObjectName(Object managedBean, String beanKey) throws MalformedObjectNameException {
        Class managedClass = AopUtils.getTargetClass(managedBean);
        String domain = ClassUtils.getPackageName(managedClass);

        Hashtable<String, String> properties = new Hashtable<>();
        properties.put("type", ClassUtils.getShortName(managedClass));
        properties.put("name", "asdsdsd");
        // ensure the application name is included as a property in the object name
        properties.put("app", "api");
        return ObjectNameManager.getInstance(domain, properties);
    }

}
```